# How can I use the compiled DLL in a client PC without installing Windows SDK?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++

I built a C++ DLL for using in C# windows application, the DLL linked to some Windows API.

However, I got error when running it on a clean Windows 7, it said "System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL".

If I install Windows SDK, then everything is okay. Anyone can tell me how I can fix without installing Windows SDK?

Comment: Why don't you want to install WSDK?

Comment: I think client's computer should not require developer tools like SDK, I don't my thought is correct or not...

Comment: The first suspect of the "missing dll" would be the C++ runtime. What happens if you only install the C++ Runtime (for the version of Visual Studio you are using) on a clean Windows 7 box? Another approach is (if you can't determine this from your code) is to use a decency viewer to identify the missing dll(s) (such as Dependency Walker). Once identified, the missing subsystem and be installed or the paths fixed to include their location.

Comment: I think it may be possible to bundle the required DLLs with your application, but I don't know.

Comment: Are you distributing a "debug" or "release" version of your dll?

Comment: You need use in installer to do it and enter to installer all your dll that you need for the program, and so you need install the file install in the computer and all will be work!

Comment: I installed Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable, but still cannot load the dll. Is there any problem if I included header files(eg. Windows.h) but cannot find the same header file on client's PC?

Comment: I am using the "debug" one.

Comment: _I am using the "debug" one_ - distributable for the C++ runtime do not include the debug version, only the release version. Build your dll in "release" mode and run that dll on the Windows 7 box.

Comment: You are not supposed to distribute the debug version. The Redistributable only contains the release version of the runtime. The debug version only comes with installing the compiler (SDK or Visual Studio).

Comment: Thanks! I try to build in release version now. thanks very much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first suspect of the "missing dll" would be the C++ runtime, it is generally not part of the Windows OS installation. What happens if you only install the C++ Runtime (for the version of Visual Studio you are using) on a clean Windows 7 box?

Another approach to determine the missing dependency (if you can't determine this from your code) is to use a dependency viewer to identify the missing dll(s) (such as [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com)). Once identified, the missing subsystem and be installed or the paths fixed to include their file location(s).

*Are you distributing a "debug" or "release" version of your dll?*

> I am using the "debug" one.

The re-distributable for the C++ runtime does not include the "debug" version, only the "release" version. Build your dll in "release" mode and run that dll on the Windows 7 box.

The "debug" versions are generally only used for debugging a dll/application and hence, the requirement then for the SDK is reasonable. In turn, when not debugging an application, the use of the SDK is not so reasonable - so you would want to distribute the "release" version to your client.